# CMake and MsVS-NuGet

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, nuget-package

I'm currently developing a desktop application, using the C++ REST SDK (codename Casablanca), Qt5 and some other libraries.

For the project setup, I use CMake.

How to get CMake to install NuGet Packages?

I now have to install it each time manually, if I rerun CMake, which isn't really an option.

Comment: This is a great question, though I suspect you are actually using wrong tool for the job. If you are windows-specific, there is no point in using CMake. The only reason to use CMake is to be mutli-platform, but than you can't use NuGet packages much. Of course I can imagine a project where most of it is multi-platform, but has some windows-specific component that needs NuGet packages and there this question makes perfect sense.

Comment: I however think that the question should have been posted to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JanHudec

a) Yes I know that, but the project setup via CMake is the easiest I know, when using libraries like Qt.

b) how that? Isn't this a bit too specific for StackOverflow?

Comment: I am sure you'll find instructions for including Qt in plain Visual Studio project much more easily than instructions how to make CMake import NuGet packages. NuGet packages can be imported with powershell commands, but you'd need to run it after generation and CMake does not execute any commands than.

Comment: @JanHudec Even windows-specific, CMake allows you to support multiple MSVC versions or MinGW/GCC.

Comment: @Andre: As long as you are only targeting one platform, there is not much need for different compilers. If you want to support, say, WinCE, WinNT (desktop, full API) and WinPhone8, there is (no VS version supports both WinCE and WinPhone8), but I'd count those as multiple platforms.

Comment: Why not just treat Casablanca as just another library and include it in your project the obvious way?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov: This *is* the obvious way. NuGet is a tool to download and install the library automatically before building.

Comment: You might want to have a look at ruslo's hunter instead of NuGet, cf. https://github.com/ruslo/hunter

Comment: @usr1234567, yet another package manager why?

Comment: @jan hudec, this question is about using nuget on windows where is no system prebuilt wide known c++ libraries like boost, qt or Casablanca which is caused the question. It is absolutely reasonable to use nuget for fetching dependencies on Windows for Visual Studio generator. Nuget is integrated part of Visual Studio IDE distributive. This is how it should be.

Comment: CMake 3.15 and higher now fully supports adding Nuget references! See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**EDIT**: This answer does not apply to C++ projects.

**EDIT**: As of CMake 3.15, CMake supports referencing Nuget packages with [`VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html). Now, this is a ***much*** cleaner solution than the work-around proposed earlier below. To add a Nuget package reference to a CMake target, use the package name and package version separated by an `_` underscore. Here is an example for `BouncyCastle` version `1.8.5`:

```
set_property(TARGET MyApplication
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "BouncyCastle_1.8.5"
)
```

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html) shows how you can add *multiple* Nuget packages by semicolon-delimiting `;` the packages.

---

For CMake versions older than 3.15, here is one potential work-around:

Kudos to @Markus Mayer for the excellent answer. I ran with the suggestion, but found that using the `nuget` command line doesn't hold up if you're generating your VS project/solution files *from scratch*. Specifically, the `nuget` command line does not update the project files (`.csproj`), and some manual effort seems necessary to tell your project where to find the installed dependencies. The following steps outline how I worked around this for a simple project with one Nuget package dependency:

1. Installed the Nuget package dependency using Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio.
2. Copied the generated `packages.config` file (generated in the same directory as the affected `.csproj` file). Placed the copy into a source directory, and renamed it as `packages.config.in`. Now, we can tell CMake to copy this file back to the CMake binary directory during the configure stage with `configure_file`. Nuget will use it to install/restore dependencies, if they are missing.
3. Took note of where Nuget installed the DLL for this package. On my machine, this was in the CMake binary directory in a `packages` directory.

We can use this path to tell CMake our reference package's location:

```
set_property(TARGET MyApplication PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_MyReferenceLib
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/path/to/lib/MyReferenceLib.dll)
```

We can also see where this dependency is installed in the `.csproj` file to verify we got the correct path (see `HintPath`), and didn't miss any other dependencies:

```
<Reference Include="MyReferenceLib, Version=2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567891234567, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>packages\path\to\lib\MyReferenceLib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

4. Uninstalled the Nuget package, because now we have all the information necessary to let CMake do all the heavy lifting.

Putting it together, the CMake commands look like this:

```
# Find Nuget (install the latest CLI here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads).
find_program(NUGET nuget)
if(NOT NUGET)
    message(FATAL "CMake could not find the nuget command line tool. Please install it!")
else()
    # Copy the Nuget config file from source location to the CMake build directory.
    configure_file(packages.config.in packages.config COPYONLY)
    # Run Nuget using the .config file to install any missing dependencies to the build directory.
    execute_process(COMMAND 
        ${NUGET} restore packages.config -SolutionDirectory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
endif()
# Provide the path to the Nuget-installed references, in case this is a fresh project build.
set_property(TARGET MyApplication PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_MyReferenceLib
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/path/to/lib/MyReferenceLib.dll)
```

While this will now also provide package paths to the VS project for fresh CMake builds, there is one caveat. If you want to upgrade the version of the Nuget-installed package you are using, you'll have to re-do the aforementioned manual steps.

TL;DR: Here is the full `CMakeLists.txt` file that I tried out with Nuget-installed SQLite:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

# Project name
project(MyProject LANGUAGES CSharp)

# Include CMake utilities for CSharp, for WinForm and WPF application support.
include(CSharpUtilities)

set(MyProject_SOURCES 
    Form1.cs
    Form1.Designer.cs
    Form1.resx
    Program.cs
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings
)

# Define the executable, including any .cs files. 
# The .resx and other Properties files are optional here, but including them makes them visible in the VS solution for easy editing. 
add_executable(MyWinFormApp ${MyProject_SOURCES})

# Set the source file properties for Windows Forms use.
csharp_set_windows_forms_properties(${MyProject_SOURCES})

# Find Nuget (install the latest CLI here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads).
find_program(NUGET nuget)
if(NOT NUGET)
    message(FATAL "CMake could not find the nuget command line tool. Please install it!")
else()
    # Copy the Nuget config file from source location to the CMake build directory.
    configure_file(packages.config.in packages.config COPYONLY)
    # Run Nuget using the .config file to installing any missing dependencies to the build directory.
    execute_process(COMMAND 
        ${NUGET} restore packages.config -SolutionDirectory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
endif()

# Set the .NET Framework version for the executable.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")

# Provide the path to the Nuget-installed references, in case this is a fresh project build.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_EntityFramework 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/EntityFramework.6.2.0/lib/net45/EntityFramework.dll)
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_EntityFramework.SqlServer 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/EntityFramework.6.2.0/lib/net45/EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll)
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_System.Data.SQLite
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.110.0/lib/net46/System.Data.SQLite.dll)
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_System.Data.SQLite.EF6 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6.1.0.110.0/lib/net46/System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll)
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_System.Data.SQLite.Linq
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Linq.1.0.110.0/lib/net46/System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll)

# Add in the .NET reference libraries.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Windows.Forms"
)
```

Comment: after from scratch you can open the generated sln and add nugets using manager, then use nuget restore

Comment: VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES  does not work for C++ projects as the original question seems to imply. Only C# is supported by MSBuild, which is documented as of today.

Comment: Arguably this answer should not be accepted. It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 25):

The command line reference of NuGet is located at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference

You can install packages using the `nuget install` or `nuget restore` command. `nuget update` updates the installed packages (`restore` must be run beforhand).

You can instruct cmake to run NuGet before every build by using:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND nuget restore ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\yourSolution.sln
)
```

or at configure time using `execute_process`.

You can prepare the nuget config file using `configure_file` or use appropriate `nuget install` commands directly.

Comment: I don't think cmake will be willing to add the nugets into the solution, so a separate config file or explicit `install` is probably needed. I would also run the installation during configuration already (via `execute_process`). It is a bit simpler and the IDE will already see the packages available when it starts.

Comment: while i'd like to test that, i have to say that i already closed the project half a year ago...(i also decided to not use the nuget related library)

Comment: could someone edit the answer and write right oneliner?

Comment: @Markus Mayer As far as I can tell, this only installs (or restores missing dependencies) from Nuget, but does not update your VS project/solution files. Thus, it appears you still have to add the project references to the Nuget-supplied libraries manually, so your projects know where they exist. Is this true?

Comment: (Late response, but still) @Kevin this seems true to me. What you really need is to be able to run a Package Manager Console command. It seems this can be done with the 3rd-party PMCCommand utility: https://github.com/benwtrent/PMCCommand

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/clarkezone/flutter_win_webview/commit/ce603ec8c96bed50e4443c49a150ce4d3d352896

```
find_program(NUGET_EXE NAMES nuget)
exec_program(${NUGET_EXE}
    ARGS install "Microsoft.Web.WebView2" -Version 0.9.579 -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages)
target_link_libraries(${PLUGIN_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/build/native/Microsoft.Web.WebView2.targets)
```

Comment: VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES work for C# but not C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909735/cmakes-vs-package-references-not-adding-a-reference-to-vs2017-project