# A NuGet-aware find_package for CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, nuget

I'm building a cross-platform library with CMake which has a few (pretty common) dependencies (e.g. PCRE). The dependencies are available through the usual package managers (APT on Ubuntu/Debian, Homebrew on OSX), and also through NuGet on Windows. In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I use the "module" version of `find_package` to locate these dependencies and set the right include/library flags.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132987/cmake-and-msvs-nuget) provides one way of integrating CMake + NuGet, but also suggests that CMake and NuGet aren't likely to play nice together, and I can't seem to find a way to get `find_package` to find the installed dependencies. Is there some way to get CMake to read the NuGet config files (ala the way `pkg_check_modules` works on systems with `pkg-config`) and populate the appropriate CMake variables from there?  Or do I have to hand-roll my own solution in `FindPCRE.cmake`?

Comment: Have you tried to add the NuGet installation paths to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH?

Comment: I'm not sure CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH would be enough, because it looks like the directory hierarchy is a little... crazy.

Comment: Yeah, it's hairy. I experimented with it, but couldn't find the magic incantations.

Comment: The problem is that there is no unified convention how to package native libraries with NuGet. Thus, every package has a unique layout and you have to account for this manually. I have a script which sets up CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH according to individual packages... :-( I am investigating vcpkg which has a unified convention for layouts.

Answer (score 7):

As a (somewhat filthy) workaround, I'm relying on the `nuget` cli tool being present and using

```
find_program(NUGET nuget)
if(NOT NUGET)
  message(FATAL "Cannot find nuget command line tool.\nInstall it with e.g. choco install nuget.commandline")
else()
  execute_process(COMMAND ${NUGET} install foolib)
endif()
```

Answer (score 3):

As of CMake 3.15, CMake now supports referencing Nuget packages with [`VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html), without the need for the Nuget CLI, or hard-coding paths to references. To add a Nuget package reference to a CMake target, we can use the syntax `<package-name>_<package-version>`. Here is a simple example for the Nuget logging package `Serilog` version 2.9.0:

```
set_property(TARGET MyLibrary
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "Serilog_2.9.0"
)
```

The linked documentation shows how you can add *multiple* Nuget packages by semicolon-delimiting `;` the package arguments.

Comment: Does this only work if you use a VS generator? Say it wouldn't work for Ninja?

Comment: @Dr.PolarHumenn Considering the documentation says that the package references will be added to the generated *Visual Studio project*, I would assume it does not work with Ninja. However, I have not tested it so I cannot say that with any certainty.