# CMake CSharp reference nuget packges

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, nuget

I have a CSharp project configured via CMake, and I have a problem referencing nuget packages. I tried to add them via:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
"../../packages/ExcelDna.Integration.0.34.6/lib/ExcelDna.Integration.dll")
```

After restoring the nuget packages, I still have to double click the reference in Visual Studio (2015) in order to compile the program successfully. Furthermore, is there a version number independent way to add references to nuget packages? And how is it possible to add `ExtensionTargets` required by some packages (e.g. ExcelDna.AddIn)?

Comment: CMake 3.15 now fully supports adding Nuget references, without the need for the manual steps you describe. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: As of CMake 3.15, CMake supports referencing Nuget packages with [`VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html). This is a cleaner solution than restoring the Nuget packages manually, and hard-coding the package paths in CMake. The `VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES` target property now handles all of that overhead for you.

To add a Nuget package reference to a CMake target, use the package name and package version separated by an underscore `_`, like this:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "ExcelDna.Integration_0.34.6"
)
```

You can grab any version number in a range, with `*`, and append multiple packages using a semicolon:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "ExcelDna.Integration_0.34.*;ExcelDna.AddIn_1.0.0"
)
```

---

You can use [`VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_<YourLibrary>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_refname.html#prop_tgt:VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_%3Crefname%3E) to get CMake to find your Nuget package references. Try this:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_ExcelDna.Integration 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/ExcelDna.Integration.0.34.6/lib/ExcelDna.Integration.dll
)
```

Note, the full DLL name must be appended to the `VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_` directive to create the full variable. However, I have not seen a version number independent way to load the Nuget packages, and I've had to manually edit my CMake files to include these packages. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132987/cmake-and-msvs-nuget/56093754#56093754) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Do I need to add `VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_<YourLibrary>` if I am using VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES to add package references to 'YourLibrary'?

Comment: I can see that the package reference is being added in the generated csproj file (also confirmed via cmake's source - https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx#L781) 
although I still see linking errors when I try to use 'YourLibrary'.

Comment: @Naman If you are using CMake 3.15 or later, you should only need `VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES` command to reference Nuget packages.