# Nuget package from CMake

Tags: c#, cmake, nuget

I am generating an C# WPF project using CMake. I followed this CMakeLists.txt [example](https://github.com/bemehiser/cmake_csharp_wpf_example/blob/master/Example/CMakeLists.txt) from Github.

My question is: How can add a Nuget package to this project using CMake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake and MsVS-NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132987/cmake-and-msvs-nuget)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake 3.15 and above supports referencing Nuget packages with [`VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html). To add a Nuget package reference to a CMake target, use the package name and package version separated by an underscore `_`. Here is an example for `BouncyCastle` version 1.8.5:

```
set_property(TARGET MyApplication
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "BouncyCastle_1.8.5"
)
```

The documentation shows how you can add *multiple* Nuget packages by semicolon-delimiting `;` the packages.

For older CMake versions, you could try the proposed work-around suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093754/3987854).