# Including nuget packages in VS2019 C++ cross platform program

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake, nuget

I've been tasked with starting to lay out a C++ cross platform program with CMake. One of our main dependencies involves in-house nuget packages. With our Windows C++ projects, I'd just right click the project and choose **Manage Nuget Packages**. In the cross platform, there's no such option, and I am struggling to find any relevant information on how I'd go about including those dependencies. Can anyone link me to any good sources of info, or demo?

Comment: For what it's worth, I feel like Microsoft's C++ team recommends vcpkg over nuget, so perhaps you could investigate that. It might work better. https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg

Comment: @Jason CMake 3.15 supports adding Nuget package references, which provides a much simpler solution. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: As of CMake 3.15, CMake supports referencing Nuget packages with [`VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html). Now, this is a ***much*** cleaner solution than the work-around proposed below. To add a Nuget package reference to a CMake target, use the package name and package version separated by an underscore `_`; here is an example for `BouncyCastle` version 1.8.5:

```
set_property(TARGET MyApplication
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "BouncyCastle_1.8.5"
)
```

Note, this solution only works for C# or hybrid C#/C++ projects. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910170/3987854), Microsoft doesn't support `PackageReference` for pure C++ projects.

---

Prior to CMake 3.15, CMake has no built-in commands for Nuget support, so you will have to use the `nuget` [command line utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference) to include Nuget dependencies using CMake.

You can use CMake's [`find_program()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) to locate the `nuget` command line utility (once installed), coupled with [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) or [`execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) to execute `nuget` commands from CMake. The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18132987/3987854) discuss in more detail, but it could essentially look something like this:

```
# Find Nuget (install the latest CLI here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads).
find_program(NUGET nuget)
if(NOT NUGET)
    message(FATAL "CMake could not find the nuget command line tool. Please install it!")
else()
    # Copy the Nuget config file from source location to the CMake build directory.
    configure_file(packages.config.in packages.config COPYONLY)
    # Run Nuget using the .config file to install any missing dependencies to the build directory.
    execute_process(COMMAND 
        ${NUGET} restore packages.config -SolutionDirectory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
endif()
```

This assumes you have an existing `packages.config` file listing the nuget dependencies for your project.

To tie dependencies to a specific target, you (unfortunately) have to use the full path to where `nuget` placed the assembly/library.

For .NET nuget packages this would look like this:

```
# Provide the path to the Nuget-installed references.
set_property(TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_MyReferenceLib
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/path/to/nuget/lib/MyReferenceLib.dll
)
```

For C++-flavored nuget packages, it could look like this:

```
add_library(MyLibrary PUBLIC
    MySource.cpp
    MyClass1.cpp
    ...
)

# Provide the path to the Nuget-installed libraries.
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/path/to/nuget/lib/MyCppLib.dll
)
```

---

As an aside, CMake **does** support the *creation* of Nuget packages with CPack. Here is the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/nuget.html#cpack_gen:CPack%20NuGet%20Generator) for the CPack Nuget generator.

Comment: I had come across that post referenced above, but had hoped things had changed in the 6 years since it had been asked.
I have the package.config file that i can port over which is not a big deal. what file would the target_link_libraries stuff go into?
so far, the learning curve looks pretty steep to get up to speed on this.

Comment: @Jason While CMake has improved to support C# as a first-class language, it unfortunately hasn't developed full support for Nuget (which is commonly used with C#). As for your `target_link_libraries()` command, you can place it directly after where you define your own C++ libraries. I expanded my answer to show this. This will *link* the Nuget-installed library to your own library. You can also add many additional Nuget dependencies to this call, as necessary.

Comment: Appreciate it. I'm gonna have to do a lot of research, i suspect.

Comment: @Jason If you are new to CMake, there is a good article [here](https://preshing.com/20170511/how-to-build-a-cmake-based-project/#the-configure-and-generate-steps) describing how the CMake magic works. The CMake tag [page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmake/info) here also has several helpful links.

Comment: just a followup after doing some research... I have the capability of generating a VS2019 solution file via cmake. At that point, i can treat it as a standard windows project and add nuget as normal. My limitation would then be creating the CmakeLists.txt for the *nix configurations. Is that an accurate statement?

Comment: The solution I provided should allow you to automate (almost, explained in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093754/3987854)) everything with CMake, and there should be no manual Nuget steps after-the-fact. On *nix configs, there is a similar `nuget` command line tool, so the same solution could be applied. I haven't tested it, so there may be a few other quirks or gotchas when using Nuget with Mono (.NET on Linux).

Comment: @squareskittles Using the cmake 3.15 solution, are there any other steps required? Cmake completes without errors or warnings, yet I don't see any nuget packages in VS.

Using `set_property(TARGET myproj PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT_2.0.200316.3")`

Comment: @scx Maybe that option works just for C# (Would you please update your info): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files
BTW: I am also trying to install references to cppwinrt? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Zingam `set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT_2.0.200316.3")`
`add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PRE_BUILD COMMAND msbuild /t:restore ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.sln)`
And finally, you add a Directory.Build.props to silence some warning.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for C++ projects so is actually NOT an answer to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909735/cmakes-vs-package-references-not-adding-a-reference-to-vs2017-project

Comment: Thanks for the commentary, I added a note to clarify the scope for this solution (C# or C#/C++ hybrid projects). As the other post dictates, there really is no proper solution for pure C++ projects.