# CMake's VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES not adding a reference to VS2017 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm trying to automatically add (nuget) references to my (C++) visual studio 2017 project using CMake.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132987/cmake-and-msvs-nuget) question, `VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES` is suggested, available from CMAKE 3.15. So, I've added the following to my CMAKE code:

```
set_property(TARGET MyApplication
    PROPERTY VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "BaseUtils.Native.Dynamic_0.4.0.38060"
)
```

And the following is nicely added to my project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
          <PackageReference Include="BaseUtils.Native.Dynamic" Version="0.4.0.38060" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

However, the reference is not show in the solution explorer, nor are any include folders added to the project. It seems that the `PackageReference` element is in no way taken into account.

Anyone any idea how to solve this? I'm using CMake 3.15.3, which doesn't give any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hmm, apparantly, C++ projects are not supported by `PackageReference` according to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)

> ASP.NET apps targeting the full .NET Framework include only limited
>   support for PackageReference. **C++ and JavaScript project types are
>   unsupported.**

This makes the whole `VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES` option from CMake inapplicable for C++ projects.

Comment: So ... is there another way to get C++ packages into VS solutions, via CMake?