# Using NuGet to fill CMake dependencies in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, nuget, dependency-management

I'm very new to developing on Windows (mostly a Linux user). I'm trying re-port [my open source library](https://github.com/etaler/Etaler) to Windows and Visual Studio. Another person have ported the project awhile ago but I want to re-do the process. And The project depends on [Intel TBB](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/threading-building-blocks.html) and the original solution was the user is responsible to install it as a dependency using the systems' package manager, Like so:

```sh
sudo pacman -Sy intel-tbb
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

Or the user usse a [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD) or let [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=etaler-git) deal with dependencies for you

```sh
makepkg -s
```

Those solutions work well on Linux. But in Visual Studio, after importing the repository. Visual Studio complaints CMake can't find TBB. Which makes sense, I don't have TBB installed. So I tried to install it using NuGet. But NuGet complains there's no default project.

```
PM> Install-Package tbb
Install-Package : Project "Default" is not found
+ Install-Package tbb
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

How can I install the needed dependencies on Windows? NuGet won't let me install packages if cmake does not pass. But CMake can't configure itself without the dependencies. Am I misusing NuGet or have a wrong concept of how NuGet works?

Comment: Can you please provide your CMake file? What is the *exact* CMake error you are receiving? Also, CMake allows you to specify NuGet dependencies for Visual Studio, see the beginning of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093754/3987854) response.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT - I'll have to try in the weekends. Pardon, but I run WIndows on the same machine as my Linux workstation. And I need Linux running in the weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

> Using NuGet to fill CMake dependencies in Visual Studio 2019

**First**, thanks to **squareskittles** for his help.

**Visual Studio** does not support using Package Manage Console or traditional way in CMake project to install nuget packages. See [this github link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6731).

**As a workaround**, you can use [VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES.html) to install nuget package in cmake project.

**Solution**

```
set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY
  VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "tbb_4.2.3.1")
```

To add a Nuget package reference to a CMake target, use the package name and package version separated by an `_`underscore.

More info, you can refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132987/cmake-and-msvs-nuget/56093754#56093754).